# Decrypt the data using the decrypted key

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt the data using private key. I was able to decrypt the key using RSA and private key. Now I would like to decrypt the data using the decrypted key. The data was encrypted the values using AES and random session secret using PHP.
Could you please let me know if there are any examples?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

        string protectedSecret = "U6XksFkhWV4.......eo3fRg==";
        var decodedSecret = Convert.FromBase64String(protectedSecret);

        string iv = "KLnP....wA==";
        var decodedIV = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\\private.key")) 
            keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

        var decryptPKIEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
        decryptPKIEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);

        var secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptPKIEngine.ProcessBlock(decodedSecret, 0, decodedSecret.Length));

        var  protectedData = Convert.FromBase64String("f8..Po=");
      }
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Now I would like to decrypt the protected data using the key. I am not sure how!. Thanks for any help.

Comment: PHP code is using AES 256 OFB cipher format while encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `RijndaelManaged` instance and set its `Key` and `IV` to your byte arrays.

Then, create a `CryptoStream` from `CreateDecryptor()` wrapping a `MemoryStream` with your ciphertext byte array.
Finally, read the plaintext from the `CryptoStream`.  (if it's actual text, you may want to use a StreamReader)

Answer (score 0):

Try this replace put the necessary strings where needed

```
static string PHPDecrypt() 
    {            
      byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("U6XksFkhWV4.......eo3fRg=="); //put in your real values here and below for iv and cipherTextBytes
      byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String("KLnP....wA=="");
      byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("Put the EncryptedText here");

      var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged 
      { 
         Mode = CipherMode.CBC, 
         IV = iv, KeySize = 256, 
         Key = keyBytes, 
         Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
      };

      using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor())
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
      using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
        var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cs.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is the actual key size in your case.. 128,256, 1024..ect.. you didn't specify that in your initial post..

Comment: The size is 256. The PHP code is using AES 256 OFB cipher format while encryption.

Comment: I am still getting "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.". Thanks for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6705/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-nav100)